# Firefox JSSH Connection or very detailed compile steps on Ubuntu 64?

Tags: firefox, watir, firewatir, jssh

I'm having a hard time getting jssh and firefox to play nice on an Ubuntu Jaunty 64-bit machine. Anyone know the specific steps needed to make this work? (or, if you're using something else to get firewatir to work, I'll take those as answers as well)

Here are a few things I tried:

1. installing the jssh extension by itself (by following the instructions in http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/FireWatir+on+Ubuntu) then running the following command line renders an error:

   firefox -jssh

   telnet localhost:9997

   **I get the error:**

   Trying ::1...

   Trying 127.0.0.1...

   telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection Refused
2. Compiling firefox with the following mozconf file and make command renders an error:

.

```
The file:
mk_add_options MOZ_CO_PROJECT=browser
mk_add_options MOZ_OBJDIR=@TOPSRCDIR@/firefox-jssh
ac_add_options --enable-extensions=default,jssh
ac_add_options --enable-application=browser

The command:
make -f client.mk

I get the Error:    

make[6]:  [WebGLContext.o] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory `/home/bernie/sources/mozilla-central/firefox-jssh/content/canvas/src'
make[5]:  [src_libs] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/bernie/sources/mozilla-central/firefox-jssh/content/canvas'
make[4]:  [canvas_libs] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/bernie/sources/mozilla-central/firefox-jssh/content'
make[3]:  [libs_tier_gecko] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/bernie/sources/mozilla-central/firefox-jssh'
make[2]:  [tier_gecko] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/bernie/sources/mozilla-central/firefox-jssh'
make[1]:  [default] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/bernie/sources/mozilla-central/firefox-jssh'
make:  [build] Error 2
```

3. Compiling

Comment: downvoting every answer is not going to encourage anyone else to try

Comment: +1 for not downvoting all answers :)

Comment: Post this to http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general, there are 1600+ Watir users there.

Comment: Check out what the last guy says on https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=586869 using the command "hg up -r 3ca5d6674feb" so far it is building for me but it does take a looong while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try fallow this instruction: (found using google but I had to correct a little bit):

You have to install some packages to checkout and successfully compile firefox

```
sudo apt-get build-dep firefox

sudo apt-get install mercurial libasound2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libnotify-dev libxt-dev libiw-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
```

then clone firefox source from repository

#### This version has problems with firefox add-ons compatibility

#### for quick workaround install this add-on http://www.oxymoronical.com/web/firefox/nightly

```
hg clone http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/

cd mozilla-central
```

Create a new file .mozconfig in current directory

```
gedit .mozconfig
```

and paste the following build options into it.

```
mk_add_options MOZ_CO_PROJECT=browser

mk_add_options MOZ_OBJDIR=@TOPSRCDIR@/firefox-jssh

ac_add_options --enable-extensions=default,jssh

ac_add_options --enable-webservices

ac_add_options --enable-application=browser
```

then do

```
autoconf2.13

cd js/src

autoconf2.13

cd ../..
```

and compile using

```
make -f client.mk build
```

#### If failure, install required packages displayed in error messages

now

```
./firefox-jssh/dist/bin/firefox -jssh

telnet localhost:9997
```

and fortunately you should see **"Welcome to the Mozilla JavaScript Shell!"**

I wish you luck, and be patient, compilation takes a while

Comment: For building try to see if what Phil Ringnalda says in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=586869 helps. Basically when you do "hg clone http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/" and then CD to the folder then do this: "hg up -r 3ca5d6674feb". Be advised the build seems to take a loong while. For the record it seems I am building a version of Firefox 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at this?

http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/FireWatir+on+Ubuntu

There is already compiled Linux XPI here:

http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/FireWatir+Installation#FireWatirInstallation-2)InstalltheJSSHFirefoxExtension

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much what I'm doing in the first try I described above. The problem is that the XPI doesn't work with Ubuntu 64, which is why it appears I have to compile it manually.

I'm really sorry, but I can't accept the answer since it begs the question. I'll add to the question just to be sure everyone's clear on what I've tried. Thank you, though, for at least trying :-)

Comment: I did not ask that my answer is accepted, but it would be nice if it was not downvoted. :)

Comment: Hi Zelijko, I'll be happy to remove the downvote. The system won't let me remove it, though, unless there's a new edit. If you add a period to the end of your answer, I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: I just wanted to say that if you do not like the answer, just ignore it. If it is wrong, downvote it. By the way, I did a small change to my answer. :)

Comment: I am Using Ubuntu 10.04 with 64 bits and using the 64 bit version for JSSH for firefox 3.6 did allow me to use firewatir. Still I had to close firefox. Call firefox from command line "firefox -jssh" and then execute my ruby script. Didn't had to use sudo for any of these steps. I am sure the firefox -jssh can be added to menu for writing less.